# How to simplify the equation of this 3D-straight line？

Tags: simplifying-expressions, geometry

Find the equation of the line passing through the point (2,1,3) and perpendicular to the line (x + 1)/3 == (y - 1)/2 == z/-1 and having an intersection point.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
s1 = {s11, s12, s13};
s2 = {3, 2, -1};
Solve[{(x0 - 2)/s11 == (y0 - 1)/s12 == (z0 - 3)/s13, (x0 + 1)/3 == (
   y0 - 1)/2 == z0/-1, s1.s2 == 0}, {x0, y0, z0, s11, s12, s13}]

(*{{x0 -> 2/7, y0 -> 13/7, z0 -> -(3/7), s11 -> -2 s12, s13 -> -4 s12}}*)
```

Then,

```
Assuming[s11 == -2 s12 && s13 == -4 s12 && s12 != 0 && 
  s12 \[Element] Reals, 
 Refine[(x - 2)/s11 == (y - 1)/s12 == (z - 3)/s13]]

(*(-2 + x)/s11 == (-1 + y)/s12 == (-3 + z)/s13*)
```

However, obviously, the equation of the line is:

(-2 + x)/-2 == (-1 + y)/1 == (-3 + z)/-4

How to get this result?

Comment: Please clarify the "definition of a line"  (x + 1)/3 == (y - 1)/2 == z/-1  !Onedimensional line should depend on one parameter.

Comment: That is the equation of a plane

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `Solve[(x + 1)/3 == (y - 1)/2 == z/-1 == t, {x, y, z}]`

Comment: @Drod There are two equations in `(x + 1)/3 == (y - 1)/2 == z/-1` so it is a line.

Comment: There isn't just one equation describing the line - you could multiply all three parts by a constant. Perhaps this is why refine isn't choosing your particular denominators.

Comment: @cvgmt The missing part `...==t`   should be part of the question!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann This is the implicit form of line,need not use `==t` We introduce`== t` just convert the implicit form to parametric form.

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you for the hint. The explicit form (vectorform) seems to me to be much more suitable for solving this problem I think.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this question does not have a unique answer. There are infinite many direction vectors dir perpendicular to a line. Therefore there are infinite many lines trough a point perpendicular to the given line: line[t_]= p0+ t dir.

Comment: Sorry, there is an error in my original question, which has been edited and corrected. The two straight lines should be both vertical and intersecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in your code

```
s11 == -2 s12 && s13 == -4 s12 && s12 != 0 && s12 \[Element] Reals
```

gives non-unique solution. In fact, the first `Solve` already indicates that the number of equations is insufficient to provide unique solution (5 eqs and 6 vars). You could simply use `FindInstance` on `{s11,s12,s13}`

```
FindInstance[ s11 == -2 s12 && s13 == -4 s12 && s12 != 0 && s12 \[Element] Reals, {s11, s12, s13}]

(*{{s11 -> 2, s12 -> -1, s13 -> 4}}*)
```

and plug this instance right into the equality. If you want it to be more consistent, try the following:

```
line = (x + 1)/3 == (y - 1)/2 == z/-1;
v = {3, 2, -1} (*line vector*);
p0 = {2, 1, 3} (*point on the other line*);
surf = ({x, y, z} - p0) . v == 0 (*equation of surface that contains p0 and has v as normal*);

(*intersection point of line and surf*)
P = {x, y, z} /. First@Solve[line && surf, {x, y, z}];
(*line equation*)
Eliminate[({x, y, z} - p0) == t*(P - p0), t]

(*x == -2 (-2 + y) && 4 y == 7 - z*)
```

If you rather prefer the three equality format,

```
(*terms in line equation, treated coordinate-wise*)
eqs = Flatten@(t /. Solve[#, t] & /@ Table[({x, y, z} - p0)[[i]] == t*(P - p0)[[i]], {i, 3}]);
(*common factor*)
lcm = PolynomialLCM @@ Coefficient[eqs, {x,y,z}];
(*output*)
eqs/lcm /. {x_, y_, z_} -> (x == y == z)

(*(2 - x)/2 == -1 + y == (3 - z)/4*)
```

Comment: The answer is very good, thank you! @Shin Kim